# how to show/hide grid row in mvc razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my View, I have a table that creates two rows for each record in the output like so:

```
<table ......>
@foreach(var obj in Model)
{
 <tr>
   <td class="toggle-class" onclick="toggle(this);">
   <td>more columns</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="additionalRows" style="display:none;">
    <td> stuff  </td>
    <td> more stuff  </td>
 </tr>
}
</table>
```

What I want to do is show or hide the second row of this record when the first's row's image is clicked.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your first `<td>` is missing a closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$(".toggle-class").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next("tr").show();
});
```

or this if you want to toggle:

```
$(".toggle-class").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next("tr").toggle();
});
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjTMh/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work?

```
<script>
$(function(){
$("table tr.toggleClass img").click(function(){
$(this).parent().next("tr").toggle();
}):
});
</script>
```